# RobotFramework: Get Return Value When Using 'Run Keyword {if, unless}'

Tags: robotframework

Getting return variables from a keyword in RobotFramework is generally easy enough, just put a return value int he keyword and run the keyword after a variable to store the return value.

I run into a problem when I want to run that keyword conditionally.  Both the `Run Keyword If` and the `Run Keyword Unless` keywords, as well as the `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` keyword, expect a keyword as the first argument and will throw an error if the first argument is a variable.

Currently I am working around this by setting suite level variables in the keywords I know I am going to run conditionally, but this feels kind of kludgy.  Worse, I have to refactor any keyword that was not forseen needed as a conditional keyword when originally designed.  Of course, I could just not use return variables, ever, and always set suite level variables, but that just makes me feel dirty.

I have not found a clean way to do this.  It works, but I was hoping someone else had found a better way.

Answer (score 7):

Those keywords you mention return the value of the keyword they run, so you can just capture the return result like you normally would.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | ${foo}= | Set variable | true
| | ${bar}= | Run keyword if | "${foo}" == "true" 
| | ... | set variable | this is bar
| | Should be equal | ${bar} | this is bar
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this question.  After I read your answer and went back and read the built in library guides and realize I could have answered the question myself if I had looked at all the examples instead of going by the fact the conditional keywords didn't specify their return value like most other keywords.  That will teach me to only look where I expect to see an answer.

Thank you again.